# Syntax to select a group of files based on extension?

Tags: wildcards, tcsh

I have several files in the following form,

Group - 1

```
file1.n001
file2.n002
file3.n003
file4.n004
:
:
:
filex.nx
```

Group - 2

```
file1.ntemp
file2.nreal
:
:etc
```

In order to remove only files, with extension `.n001 to .nx` (i.e files in the first group) using `rm` command, is there a way to specify all numbered extensions in a short from (something like `rm *.n001-x`). Instead of `rm *.n001 *.n002 *.n003 ..... *.nx`.

Comment: try `ls *.n???`

Comment: @RomeoNinov what if there is file.ntmp ?

Comment: @IbnFulan, did you try it (with `ls` command)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, yes, I have. It returns `file.ntmp`. But OP probably doesn't want to remove file.ntmp.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, Yes, I don't want to remove .ntemp file,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does x mean zero-padded three-digit numbers number (file.n089,file.n678) or alphabet (file.na,file.nb,file.nx,file.ny). If it is first one, then it is super easy. Assuming you are using bash 4.1.2 or later (I don't know since when it is supported but it works in 4.1.2).

```
rm ./file*.n{001..x}
```

for i in {001..x}; do rm file'$i'
It'll remove all file ending with zero-padded three-digit numbers. Replace  x with the last number. But it also matches file2.n003. 
If x means alphabet then also do this

```
rm ./file*.n{a..x}
```

**Edit**:
For `tcsh`, also it doesn't match names like file4.n003

```
foreach i ( `seq 1 x` ) 
rm file$i.n`printf "%0yd\n" $i`
end
```

Change x to highest value and y to highest number of digits. It is a bit slow as it calls `rm` x-times. It can be made faster by appending the file names in a string and passing the string to `rm`. Also I don't know how to write tcsh script in one line.

Comment: `rm ./file*.n{001..x} ` is working well, when I do `ls ./file*.n{001..096} `, it is showing only the files in group-1. However, it is woking only in **bash**, I am using **tcsh** shell, is there a way to do this in **tcsh**

Comment: @The_Learner, see edit.

Comment: @ilkkachu, what OP hasn't clarified in post is that if x is a number. That's why I gave two statement. Also, read the line that follows the script, **Replace x with the last number**

Comment: @IbnFulan, ok, good point...

Answer (score 4):

If `x` is supposed to be some three-digit number, you could use

```
rm ./*.n[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

That would match any three-digit suffix and should work in a standard shell and as far as I can test, also works in tcsh.

In zsh, you could use

```
rm ./*.n<1-999>
```

which actually looks at the *number*, and not just the sequence of characters, so allows finer control of the numeric range. Though note that it disregards leading zeroes, so would also match e.g. `foo.n12`.

Of course, if the `x` is a literal `x`, then you'll have to add `./*.nx` to the command line separately. Or `./*.n[a-x]`. Or `./*.n?`. Or whatever it is you need.

Comment: Is it `tcsh` compatible (I don't know). OP wants to use in `tcsh`

Comment: @IbnFulan, worked as far as I tested in tcsh, yes.

Comment: @IbnFulan From `tcsh` you could also do `zsh -c 'rm ./*.n<001-999>'`

Comment: Provided OP has `zsh` installed.

Comment: Note that in zsh, `<001-999>` is the same as `<1-999>`. Both would match on `001` (or 1, 01, 000000001....)

Comment: See also `[0-9](#c3)` with `extendedglob` (same as ksh93's `{3}([0123456789])` or `bash`'s `[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yeah, I was wondering that `{n}(...)` was missing from Bash

Comment: Yes, `bash -O extglob` only has the ksh88 ones, not the ones added in ksh93.